# Куда сохранить объект в nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

Мне нужно сохранить объект между разными запросами. На пример в одном запросе по адресу / я создаю, а потом по адресу /edit я получаю его и что то делаю. Без БД и т.д. И он должен быть разных для разных соединений. У меня получилось сохранить в req.app.locals.obj, но тогда он один. Пробовал в сессию, так вроде правильно, но я делаю апи запросы просто из статичной странички через js и сессия не работает почему-то.

Запрос

```
 const promise = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/?width=${this.width}&height=${this.height}`,{credentials: true });
```

Обработчики

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const width = req.query.width;
    const height = req.query.width;
    const field = new Field(width, height);
    field.initField();
    req.app.locals.field = field;
    req.session.field = field;
    console.log(req.session.field);
    res.json(field);
});

app.get('/field', (req, res) => {
    res.json(req.session.field); 
});
```

Comment: Вероятно, вы в своих запросах через js пропустили `withcredentials: true`, в результате чего куки не передаются, и сессия не работает. Приведите кусок кода, где вы отправляете запрос на сервер

Comment: Написал. Вот у меня есть 2 обработчика. Первый при загрузке отправляеться, второй по нажатию кнопки. Нужно во втором запросе получить обьект field, который что я создал в первом.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `credentials: true` на `credentials: "same-origin"`

Comment: причем здесь origin? Вы наверно не так поняли. Страничка не на сервера. Она вообще отдельно, наверно поэтому нет сессии.

Comment: А на диск сохранить?

Comment: Без кук сессия работать не будет. credentials у fetch может принимать значения omit, same-origin, или include [источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch). Как оно воспринимает true - я не знаю, но по всей видимости куки не пересылаются, иначе сессия бы работала

Comment: и какой мне нужен credentials?

Comment: Наверно сесия не работает когда страничка html не хостится на сервере, а я ее просто открываю с диска.

Comment: Может быть, хранить на сервере объект с уникальными идентификаторами запросов. Передавать в первом и во втором запросе один и тот же id.

`http://localhost:3000/?width=5&height=6&sess_id=abc123`

`http://localhost:3000/field?sess_id=abc123`
На сервере в обработке / класть в объект значение:
`sessionObject[req.query.sess_id] = field;`
В обработке /field брать значение из объекта:
`console.log(sessionArray[req.query.sess_id]);`

Answer (score -1):

можно поробывать глобальные переменные

```
global.var = 1
```

ну или посмотреть в сторону express state - [github](https://github.com/yahoo/express-state)

Comment: Разве глобальная переменная не будет одна для всех пользователей?